# Install encfs in arch linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

For demonstration purposes I need to set up encfs in arch linux using https://copy.sh/v86/?profile=archlinux

When I try `sudo pacman -S encfs` I got a ton of errors like this one

*Could not resolve host*

Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

The `could not resolve host` error means that your server can't resolve domains during a process. Try doing something like `ping google.com` in order to see if you have the same. If yes, you have to configure DNS servers in your system.

If you don't know which DNS you can use, ask for your network admin ; if you don't have network admin there is some public DNS accross the web, ones of google are :

```
- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes when you have not updated packages for a while. Try the following commands:

```
pacman -Syu
pacman -S pacman-mirrorlist
```

and then try again installing encfs.
If it does not help and you have a custom mirrorlist, try chosing other mirrors, maybe the ones you have on top of the list don't work anymore.